# I am trying to install MCScanX-transposon but it says makefile not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, make, error-handling

[image]
I am trying to install MCScanX. MCscanX was installed successfully but I am getti9ng error while installing MCScanX-transposon. When I write make, it says no target specified. I also tried ./configure but getting similar error.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: While you are replacing your screenshots with text, also add the content of the `MCScanX-transposon` directory. Since the error message seems to be that `./configure` is not found, I conclude that you did not copy `configure` to this directory.